# Try Catch on a custom HttpException fires when returning null

Tags: firebase, error-handling, try-catch, alert, catch2

When I run my app with the code below, even if the `responseData['error']` returns `null`, I still get an error that is thrown to my `HttpException` for error handling and it returns the `catch` portion of the try catch block of my error handling. Thus every time I test my signup authorization, which successfully enrolls in firebase, I get an alert popup saying "Could not authenticate you. Please try again later."

***Provider catching the error***

```
final response = await http.post(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'email': email,
            'password': password,
            'returnSecureToken': true,
          },
        ),
      );
      final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
      print(responseData['error']);
      if (responseData['error'] != null) {
        throw HttpException(responseData['error']['message']);
      }
} catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
```

***Login/SignUp Screen***

```
try {
      if (_authMode == AuthMode.Login) {
        // Log user in
        await Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).login(
          _authData['email'].toString(),
          _authData['password'].toString(),
        );
      } else {
        // Sign user up
        await Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).signup(
          _authData['email'].toString(),
          _authData['password'].toString(),
        );
      }
    } on HttpException catch (error) {
      var errorMessage = 'Authentication failed';
      if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_EXISTS')) {
        errorMessage = 'This email address is already in use.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_EMAIL')) {
        errorMessage = 'This is not a valid email address';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('WEAK_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'This password is too weak.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('EMAIL_NOT_FOUND')) {
        errorMessage = 'Could not find a user with that email.';
      } else if (error.toString().contains('INVALID_PASSWORD')) {
        errorMessage = 'Invalid password.';
      }
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      const errorMessage =
          'Could not authenticate you. Please try again later.';
      _showErrorDialog(errorMessage);
    }
```

Comment: `catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }` PLEASE don't do this.  You just threw away your stack trace.  If you're not doing anything to recover in the catch, REMOVE the catch entirely.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz- thanks! I have the bottom catch for any other errors that may occur (ie a network error). I guess I should just move that line of code up into the If statement as an ‘’’else’’’

Comment: No, just remove the part I referenced.  Oh wait.  You don't even need try then  So remove try/catch entirely from that first code.

Comment: I still got the error after removing the try/catch on the provider. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, my advice wasn't to fix your problem, but to restructure your code so you don't lose stacktraces.  I'm betting you're getting an empty string for `responseData['error']` which of course is not null.  Can you verify what's in that value?

Comment: when I print responseData['error'], it actually does state null which is why I am confused